# More Service Fabric Actors Unit Testing and Dependency Injection

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Does anyone have suggestions for getting around the fact that ActorProxy.ActorProxyFactory is an internal static readonly member?

This post helped me get started but the proxy factory is still an issue.
[Service Fabric Unit Testing and Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725455/service-fabric-unit-testing-and-dependency-injection)

I could just add a test constructor to inject a mock factory but that means all the code has to use the injected member and not the standard ActorProxy.Create.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also have a look at this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceFabric.Mocks/) package and [documentation](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/master/README.md) that may help. It's a mock library for service fabric. That will help you mock both state and actor/service proxies.

It's important that you use `new ActorProxyFactory().CreateActorProxy` to create the `ActorProxy`, instead of using the static `ActorProxy.Create` method and then getting the factory.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Haven't tried using it yet but seems very promising.

Comment: I've tried using the Mocks package and have an issue. I get an exception when the actor service is trying to create a state provider because its not mocked.

Comment: It seems like you've resolved your issue yourself. Correct?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out the latest release of the Service Fabric SDK, they have opened up a few methods of injection (see the release notes .docx contained in the download)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/09/13/release-of-service-fabric-sdk-2-2-207-and-runtime-5-2-207/